# pysnmp prettyPrint translates OID names

Tags: python, pysnmp

I am trying to get the `MIB` in raw format OID-value. With  `lookupNames = False, lookupValues = False` I get what I want but when trying so get it in lets say CSV format:

```
(pname, pval) = (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint())
```

prettyPrint alters the values:

```
# name: 1.3.6.1.2.1.15.3.1.4.30.30.24.4

# pname: RFC1213-MIB::mib-2.15.3.1.4.30.30.24.4
```

is there any way to avoid this please and get just the full numerical OID ??

I have pysnmp (4.3.9).

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to use the [pysnmp hlapi API](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/mib-tweaks.html#waive-mib-lookup) which takes a single `lookupMib=False` parameter and with pysnmp 4.3.9 it seems to produce pure OIDs.

Also, there is a way to get rid of SNMP types completely. You can call `tuple()` on the OID values so you get a tuple of integer sub-OIDs.  Likewise, you could call `int` on numeric SNMP values and `str` on string SNMP values to get Python objects of built-in types. The catch is that you first have to [figure out](http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/docs/type/univ/objectidentifier.html#pyasn1.type.univ.ObjectIdentifier.isSuperTypeOf)  the SNMP type you deal with to do appropriate type casting.